# Cloudwatch event is not triggering my lambda function, even though it's a target

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda function that takes in a dataset name, and creates a new lambda specifically for that dataset. Here's the code that sets this up:

```
    lambda_response = lambda_client.create_function(
        FunctionName=job_name,
        Runtime='python3.6',
        Role=role_name,
        Handler='streaming_data_lambda.lambda_handler',
        Code={
            'S3Bucket': code_bucket,
            'S3Key': 'streaming_data_lambda.py.zip'
        },
        Timeout=30,
    )
```

This appears to be creating a lambda correctly, and works when I kick it off manually. I want to have this created lambda run once an hour, so the original lambda script creates the following rules and targets:

```
rule_response = event_client.put_rule(
    Name=rule_name,
    ScheduleExpression=schedule_expression
)

event_client.put_targets(
    Rule=rule_name,
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': lambda_response['FunctionName'],
            'Arn': lambda_response['FunctionArn'],
            'Input': json.dumps(input_string)
        }
    ]
)
```

where input_string is just something like {"datasetName": "name"}. I can see the rule in the CloudWatch Rules UI, and can see it's linked to the correct lambda and the input text is present. It triggers correctly every hour also, but fails to invoke the lambda function. If I look at the lambda in the UI and add the CloudWatch event rule I created as a trigger in the Designer section there, then it correctly kicks off the lambda, but is there some way to set this up in Python so I don't have to do this last step in the UI?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For anyone who might be looking for the answer to this in the future - you need to add add permission for cloudwatch events to invoke your lambda function, like so:

```
    lambda_client.add_permission(
         FunctionName=lambda_response['FunctionName'],
         StatementId=some_random_number,
         Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
         Principal='events.amazonaws.com',
         SourceArn=rule_response['RuleArn']
    )
```

Comment: Not viable solution if you want to have (a lot of) dynamically created rules since you will hit lambda policy limits (20kb).

Answer (score 2):

You may need to add

```
event_client.enable_rule(Name=rule_name)
```

After the put_rule

In this bit, there is possibly some extra config that the UI adds

```
event_client.put_rule(
Name=rule_name,
ScheduleExpression=schedule_expression)
```

try using "DescribeRule" on this rule after it is enabled and working and then duplicate any missing fields ( like RoleArn ) in the python

Answer (score 1):

The answer mentioned by @meowseph_furbalin will work but the issue with this answer is that for each rule it'll add new resource policy to the lambda. AWS limit the maximum size of resource policies to be around 2KB, so after hitting that limit, the target will not be triggered.
One way to overcome this issue is to add wildcard matching to the lambda so that it can match every rule from a single resource policy.

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name lambda_name\
--action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' --principal events.amazonaws.com \
--statement-id '1' \
--source-arn arn:aws:events:us-west-2:356280712205:rule/*
```

After adding this command you don't need to add permissions dynamically to the lambda, and you'll lambda will accept all the cloudwatch rules with a single resource policy.

- Please keep in mind while creating cloudwatch rule, you have to keep the SID as '1' for all rules. If you want to change the SID then add another rule corresponding to that SID.